# Lumen 5.7 JSON response limit

Tags: php, json, laravel, lumen

I have a large piece of text in my DB stored and can successfully pull it from my `DB`, `dd()` it and `log::debug()` the content with no issues. The text can be seen here: https://pastebin.com/KQNYW623

The problem comes when I try to return a JSON response of the text. On a clean Lumen 5.7 install in the `api.php` route file I have this route:

`$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return json_encode("*insert large content here*"); //this is where the big text goes, I won't paste it fully here but it's here in my code as a string
});`

If I access this route, I get a blank page. Absolutely nothing appears in either my screen, Postman or `curl`. There's no errors in the error logs, nothing. Just blank.

If I place anything else that is much smaller than the large text (like hello world) I have no problem outputting the response. Can someone please shed some light on what the root cause of this issue is? Is there a character limit for responses in Lumen/Laravel?

--- UPDATE ---

So if I do `echo response()->json($string)` (where `$string`) is a variable that holds the long text) I can see the string has been encoded into JSON and the response headers have been added and all this is outputted on screen. However, doing `return response()->json($string)` still continues to return a blank response.

Would anyone know why the `return` is not sending back the data from the `response()`?

Comment: That's not exactly huge.. and I don't think I've had issues or seen anyone have issues with Lumen not being able to handle large json data.  I could be mistaken though.

Comment: As the link you have provided is just a huge string, what happens when you don't `json_encode` it but still return it?

Comment: Why are you using `json_encode` in a string an not an array? It will onlye display the same string.

Comment: ^^ Puzzling one for sure... I presume you (OP) wants to pass JSON into it eventually maybe?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte the string is part of a bigger array but the problem all stems with having the string inside the array and trying to return that array as a JSON response. If I remove the big string from the array, it returns the JSON response fine

Comment: I see. Could you post the entire code here?

Comment: @Dammeul yeah this one is throwing me off. The model returned as a JSON object response fine until we added the large amount of text into the DB column. The string provided in the example is the content from that database column

Comment: @Dammeul ok so as a text string, the response is still blank when going `return response($string);`. However, outside of Lumen (i.e at the top of the `public/index.php` file) if I do `echo json_encode($string)` works no problem and can even extend the string. Obviously, something to do with Laravel's & Symphony's response libraries that don't like the length of the string

Comment: @FelippeDuarte here:

`$org = Organisation::where('companyid', $companyId)->firstOrFail();
return $response->json($org);`

The big string is a cell in a column in the Organisation model/database table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem: a CORS middleware class that I picked up from here: [enter link description here](https://www.codementor.io/chiemelachinedum/steps-to-enable-cors-on-a-lumen-api-backend-e5a0s1ecx)

Responses with a `Content-Length` > 6K were being manipulated to have a length of 0 but still return a 200 response. Thanks for the help and advice to all.

Answer (score 0):

To return a json response with lumen like laravel, I think you can look at:

[https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#json-responses)

> The json method will automatically set the Content-Type header to application/json, as well as convert the given array to JSON using the json_encode

Also if you have a Model associated to your database you can automatically cast your json into array see:

> if your database has a JSON or TEXT field type that contains serialized JSON, adding the array cast to that attribute will automatically deserialize the attribute to a PHP array

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

Comment: Yeah I'm doing this already. The problem is when doing `return response()->json($model);` with the string being part of the `$model` array, the response is blank. The issue is the large string being in the database and trying to output the model as a JSON response

Comment: @Caleuanhopkins but if you log your data using `dd` the json appears?

Comment: Coming straight from the database through Eloquent, yes it appears.

Comment: Your data through Eloquent are coming from what data type?

Comment: The data is coming straight from an Eloquent model:
`org = Organisation::where('companyid', $companyId)->firstOrFail();`

Comment: Can you share your migration?

Comment: Also i think this HTML sequence `&lt;p&gt;` from you json can broke lumen responses

Comment: I've tried with just plain text and the issue still happens when the string becomes very long. At about 8000 characters the JSON response is just blank

Comment: What is you webserver?

Comment: AWS EC2 Medium running PHP 7.2 and Apache. I have tried `ini_set('memory_limit','-1'); ` and didn't fix the issue

Comment: Can you open a dev console in a browser and tell me the response code?

Comment: every time is a 200 response, hence why no debug logs or error logs appear for it

Comment: @Caleuanhopkins i have read multiple topics and it can be an issue with Apache or php try to increase response max size